# если значение Value совпадает с одним из ключей

Tags: javascript

Есть объект с ключами.

```
const Icons = {
    D: Icon1,
    Z: Icon2,
    P: Icon3
}
```

нужно сделать проверку -- если значение `value` совпадает с одним из ключей. без `getOwnProperty`

так не выходит

```
Object.keys(Icons).forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item === value) {
                ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys` вернет вам массив ключей объекта `Icons`, `Object.values` - значения этого объекта, можно их объединить и проверять наличия значение среди ключей, с помощью `incudes`

```
const Icons = {
    D: Icon1,
    Z: Icon2,
    P: Icon3
}

if(Icons[value]) {
    // что-то делаем
}
```

**UPD**

```
getIcon(ext) {
    const Icons = {
        DOC: Icon1,
        ZIP: IconZip,
        PDF: Icon2,
    };

    return Icons[ext] ? <Icons[ext] /> : null
}
```

Comment: спасибо. только нужно сравнивать наоборот со значением ключа. D Z P. Поиск по ключам. если значение есть среди ключей объекта, то...

Comment: @werty, еще раз, вам нужно узнать, есть ли среди значений объект ключ из этого объекта?

Comment: есть ли среди ключей объекта (D, Z,P) value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2mt772Lf/

Comment: то есть если такой формат файла есть(формат-это ключи объекта), то отрисовывать картинку, если нет, то ничего не отрисовывать

Comment: попоравила. там value

Comment: @werty, просто проверки на `undefined` хватит в вашем случае

Comment: не выходит так

 (Icons[value]) ? {return <Icon
            {...this.props} size={39}
            classes='document__icon'
        />} : null;

Comment: @werty, в ответе же написано как (без фигурных скобочек и `return` в начале)

Comment: Да. поняла! спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @werty, отметьте ответ как правильный, если он решает вашу проблему